# How to (semi)-automatically convert Java Optional to Kotlin nullable types?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

My old Java code uses `Optional` a lot (as a way to workaround null pointer exceptions). Now I am migrating it to Kotlin. I do use the java-to-kotlin auto converter in Intellij IDEA, but it keeps `Optional` there.

What I want:

```
Optional<B> hello(Optional<A> a) {...}
```

auto convert to

```
fun hello(a: A?): B? {...}
```

It is OK if doing it in a semi-automatic way. My naive thoughts is regexp matching and replacing, but hope there exists a better solution.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: There is no general-purpose way to do this built into IntelliJ.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I know. Just wondering whether there are some smart workarounds

Comment: Just in case, here is the feature request for that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-14308

Comment: IntelliJ has also a "Structural Replace" feature, try replacing Optional<$T$> with $T$?

Comment: @JohannesOehm Sounds interesting! That should definitely be better than a naive regex replace. Thanks!